# If $g^3 = e$ for all $g \in G$, then $hgh^{-1}$ and $g$ commute for all $h,g \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is an exercise from a lecture on Introduction to group theory and it is given in the introductory part so I am not sure what methods to use to prove this. It is given right after an exercise that if $g^2=e$ for all $g \in G$ then $G$ is abelian, so I assume this problem can be solved with similar basic algebraic manipulations but I have got stuck on it.

Suppose that $g^3 = e$ for all $g \in G$ for a group $G$. Then show that $hgh^{-1}$ and $g$ commute for all $h,g \in G$.

I've been thinking about this problem for a while but I can't figure out a way to show this. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to show

$$\begin{align}
[hgh^{-1},g]&=\color{purple}{hgh^{-1}}\color{orange}g(\color{purple}{hgh^{-1}})^{-1}\color{orange}{g}^{-1}\\
&=(hg\underbrace{h)(h}_{h^{-1}}gh)g^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1}\\
&=(hgh)^2g^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1}\\
&=(hgh)^{-1}g^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1}\\
&=h^{-1}g^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1}\\
&=(h^{-1}g^{-1})^3\\
&=e.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

The question can be read in a somewhat different way: if a group $G$ has [exponent](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponent+of+a+group) $3$, then all the conjugacy classes of $G$ are commutative sets. The latter is equivalent to all the centralisers of elements of $G$ being *normal* subgroups. In fact, this only holds for so-called $2$-Engel groups ($[[x,g],g]=1$ for all $x,g \in G$), for details see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816442/finite-groups-of-which-the-centralizer-of-each-element-is-normal). Groups of exponent $3$ are $2$-Engel, which is easy to prove. The converse is not true in general, as the quaternion group of order $8$ shows.